# How to access my Google sheets programatically in a headless console application?

Tags: google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-apps

In my company, there are some sheets with information I need to check/update periodically. It's kinda a chore. I'd like to automate it. I created my test application in google Clound console, added an API key and set up permissions to read/write google sheets.

But from there on, all tutorials are focused on web application that will ask visitor to login with google (using a popup I guess?) and that gives the OAUTH token. To even do that, you need to generate another key, OAuth client ID and provide the URL to redirect to to collect the generated access token if the user allows access.

I don't need or want any of that. I can't provide a valid URL for redirect as the script should run on a headless VM on company VPN. I also don't even want to authenticate other users, it's just for me.

I need this to run periodically and interact with other software on my VM. I can't use Google apps script, because it cannot send any information to my VM.

So, if one wants to make a console application that does something with a google sheet, on a headless system with no server, what are the right steps? Couldn't it at least use google authenticator android app instead and let me type the code in when I run the script?

Comment: About `there are some sheets with information I need to check/update periodically.`, in this case, who is the owner of the Spreadsheet? For example, a user is the owner of it? Or, do all users have each Spreadsheet? If the Spreadsheet is only one and you have the write permission, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current situation and your expected result, for example, as a simple method, how about using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: When the Web Apps is used, your goal might be able to be achieved by a simple method. As an important point, when you use Web Apps, how many users will concurrently access the Web Apps? I thought that it is required to know it. But, if this was not included in your expectred result, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I can't really use Apps Script. The information from the sheets must make its way to the VM where it will be used to affect other things that are running there. Basically, I want to do the exact same things as I do in browser, but from a headless VM. I don't own the sheets, but I can read and write to them.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.